# Is there a universal ADB interface for microcontrollers?

Tags: adb

ADB is a great tool to communicate between my PC and android device. I was wondering to save space with hobby projects, if it is possible for ADB to be used by a microcontroller? The only reference of such an attempt I've come across is from an XDA [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/adb-interface-for-microcontrollers.1013440/) where the author created an ADB interface for the microcontroller, which would enable control of sensors and motors directly from the phone. However, the provided links were mostly inactive regarding source and didn't have detailed explanation of the process leading to the final product.

Comment: On phone/device side adb is designed to be executed in a Linux environment as a daemon process. As most microcontrollers do not provide a high-level OS like Linux adaption will be difficult. Als adb is a protocol that is provided by Android to be used e.g. by a PC. The opposite direction (Android controls other Android device or devices that support adb) is not provided by Android or it's SDK.

Comment: @Robert thank you for the detailed explanation. I have stumbled across this [repo](https://github.com/cstyan/adbDocumentation) and wonder with a deep dive in the understanding of the protocol I can achieve a communication ?

Comment: If you just want to implement adb protocol this might be possible if the microcontroller allows you to program it's USB part. However most of the adb functionality will be not applicable to a microcontroller as most have no file-system and also no shell. So the question remains what you want to use adb for.

Comment: The bare minimum would be to restart the machine with `adb reboot` on a timer.

Answer (score 3):

I never heard of it before. Pretty interesting.. and also a great website (talking of the content lol)

*This is a partial answer - About the inactive links*

Seeing that the website was working, I was sure that the links must have been changed without the proper redirects and apparently I was correct.

> Not working links on the XDA post:
>
> `http://robots-everywhere.com/re_wiki/index.php?title=PropBridge` (only
> source for now)
>
> `http://robots-everywhere.com/re_wiki/index.php?title=Serial_on_Android_using_the_audio_port`

I couldn't find what it's refering to by "PropBridge" in the first link, but I found the second link:

https://www.robots-everywhere.com/re_wiki/pub/web/Cookbook.AudioSerial.html

You can find the list here:
https://www.robots-everywhere.com/re_wiki/pub/web/Cookbook.Cookbook.html